# find and print file path, without filename

Tags: linux, awk, rhel

Please check the below

```sh
awk '/SOURCE/ {print $3}' /MAC/Delete_Name.txt | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do find /OS/ -iname "$file.pdf" ; done
```

This results in output like this:

```
/OS/001DAY/11file/cooke.pdf
```

We want it to only print the file's path, like this:

```
/OS/001DAY/11file/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that could be optimised (e.g. build up a regex from the contents of `Delete_Name.txt` and use -`find` `-iregex` rather than `-name`, so you only have to run `find` once rather than once per line in `Delete_Name.txt`) but the obvious error is that $file doesn't seem to be defined anywhere - you're reading the `awk` output into `$line`, not `$file`.

Maybe try something like this:

```sh
awk '/SOURCE/ {print $3}' /MAC/Delete_Name.txt | 
while IFS= read -r file; do 
    find /OS/ -iname "$file.pdf"
done | sed -e 's:[^/]*$/::'
```

(this can be all on one line, i've just split it onto multiple lines for readability and to avoid horizontal scrollbars on this site)

As well as correcting the mentioned error, I've set `IFS=` and used the `-r` option on the `while read`, which will read in an entire line at a time (even if the line contains spaces or tabs) and assign the entire line to $file.

The following `find -regex` version runs `find` only once, no matter how many files are listed in `/MAC/Delete_Name.txt`.   It requires the GNU or FreeBSD version of `find` for the `-iregex` option.

```sh
regexp=$(awk '/SOURCE/ {print $3}' /MAC/Delete_Name.txt  | 
         sed -n -e '1,$H; ${ g; s/\n/\\|/g ; s/^\\|//p}')

find /OS/ -iregex ".*\($regexp\)\.pdf$" | sed -e 's:[^/]*$/::'
```

Warning: if there are many files in `/MAC/Delete_Name.txt`, the constructed regexp will be too large to fit in a single command line and the `find` command will fail.  Depending on the shell, the OS and versions of same, the limit is likely to be several thousand characters per shell command line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,the last questions --  The final print is '/OS/20150711/n1.pdf' ,which options could only print the '/OS/20150711/'

Comment: That's easily stripped off with sed.  pipe the output to `sed -e 's:^.*/::'` - that will strip everything up to the last `/` on each output line.  I'll add it that my examples

Comment: thank you so much,I had tested it again,but the final print is only filename.What we need is the file paths.but the file paths didnot include the filename

Comment: sorry, i somehow managed to misread that.  you want the path only, not the filename only.  i'll fix that.

Comment: @Andy more than just thank the author of an answer to your questions, you may vote up the answer that you find good/useful, and you should accept the one answer that fits to your problem ( = that fits best if there are several answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just `find`, using `-printf`. From [`man find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=CentOS%205.6&arch=default&format=html):

```
  %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last ele-
         ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
         in the current directory) the  %h  specifier  expands  to
         ".".
```

Therefore:

```
awk '/SOURCE/ {print $3}' /MAC/Delete_Name.txt | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do find /OS/ -iname "$file.pdf" -printf "%h\n" ; done
```