# Only print filepath,without filename

Tags: linux, rhel, find, printing

The  `find` command

```
find /MOS -name "001.txt"
```

The print

> /MOS/XNF/N01/001.txt

**My questions**

**Which option could only print the filepath,without the filename ?**

The print

> /MOS/XNF/N01/

Comment: Possible duplicate: [find and print file path, without filename](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242494/12779)

Comment: Can you tell us how the question differs from the other you asked recently?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
find /MOS -printf "%h\n"
```

To only list the directory names.

See `man find` and look for `-printf format`. You will find a very detailed explanation of the format possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `sed`.

```
find /MOS -name "001.txt" | sed -re 's/[^/]+$//g'
```

This will bring the following (sans 001.txt).

> /MOS/XNF/N01/